# What are "descendant tables" in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Database dumps from Postgresql use `ALTER TABLE ONLY tablename` instead of `ALTER TABLE tablename` which I am familiar with. I was curious what the `ONLY` keyword does, so I looked it up in the [Postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html#idm46428679939072), and it says the following:

> *name*
>
> The name (optionally schema-qualified) of an existing table to alter. If ONLY is specified before the table name, only that table is altered. If ONLY is not specified, the table and all its descendant tables (if any) are altered. Optionally, * can be specified after the table name to explicitly indicate that descendant tables are included.

What are descendant tables?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> PostgreSQL implements table inheritance, which can be a useful tool
>   for database designers. (SQL:1999 and later define a type inheritance
>   feature, which differs in many respects from the features described
>   here.)
>
> Let's start with an example: suppose we are trying to build a data
>   model for cities. Each state has many cities, but only one capital. We
>   want to be able to quickly retrieve the capital city for any
>   particular state. This can be done by creating two tables, one for
>   state capitals and one for cities that are not capitals. However, what
>   happens when we want to ask for data about a city, regardless of
>   whether it is a capital or not? The inheritance feature can help to
>   resolve this problem. We define the capitals table so that it inherits
>   from cities:

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
    name            text,
    population      float,
    altitude        int     -- in feet
);

CREATE TABLE capitals (
    state           char(2)
) INHERITS (cities);
```

> In this case, the capitals table inherits all the columns of its
>   parent table, cities. State capitals also have an extra column, state,
>   that shows their state.
>
> In PostgreSQL, a table can inherit from zero or more other tables, and
>   a query can reference either all rows of a table or all rows of a
>   table plus all of its descendant tables. The latter behavior is the
>   default.

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/ddl-inherit.html

Comment: It is worth pointing out that PostgreSQL discourages the use of `inheritance`: [source](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_table_inheritance)

Answer (score 2):

Descendant tables of a table are all tables that [inherit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-inheritance.html) from it, either directly or indirectly.  So if table `B` inherits table `A`, and table `C` inherits table `B`, then:

- Tables `B` and `C` are descendant tables of `A`.
- Table `C` is a descendant table of `B`.

A query against a table (without `ONLY`) is a query against the table and all descendant tables.  So, for example, a `SELECT` on a table with descendant tables is effectively a `UNION` of `SELECT ... FROM ONLY` across that table and all of its descendant tables.  (In fact, if you inspect the query plan for a `SELECT` query on a table with descendants, you'll see that the plan is nearly identical to such a `UNION` query.)

If you are not using table inheritance, then the `ONLY` keyword has no effect on queries, as the set of descendant tables is empty.